# Splice removing incorrect index react

Tags: reactjs

I know this question has been asked time and time again but I seem to be running into the same issue as others. I am attempting to add/remove textareas, but when using splice, I seem only to be removing the last element added regardless of what I try to delete.

EDIT: Solution was to ensure the entire state is controlled. This means textareas should have values in the state that are updated when text is entered/deleted.

Comment: What is the purpose of `this.setState({});` at the end of `removeText()`? (And also, the splice is direct state manipulation, which is generally not a good idea)

Comment: You're mutating state on this line: `this.state.addText.splice(index, 1);` and that's why you have unexpected behavior. [You should never mutate state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#:~:text=Never%20mutate%20this.state%20directly%2C%20as%20calling%20setState()%20afterwards%20may%20replace%20the%20mutation%20you%20made.%20Treat%20this.state%20as%20if%20it%20were%20immutable.)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your example and it works although I agree with the other answers that this is not a correct way of working.

The problem though is, I assume, in a part of your code that you did not include. The part where you use addText. I think that is called after delete again.

Suggestions:

- consider other namings. addText as a function AND a state is confusing
- take the array from the state, splice it and put it back in the state

Comment: Okay, I changed addText to be "textBoxes" and implemented the second change (using Pratik's code below. It still seems to be deleting the last index, despite the right index being logged in the console when the delete button is pressed. Do you potentially have any other advice? Appreciate your response immensely

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED MY CODE** so it does not mutate original state

```js
  removeText(index) {
    console.log(index);
    const addTextArray = [...this.state.addText];
    addTextArray.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({...this.state, addText: [...addTextArray]});
  }
```

Comment: `Array.splice` mutates an array and you [should never mutate state in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#:~:text=Never%20mutate%20this.state%20directly%2C%20as%20calling%20setState()%20afterwards%20may%20replace%20the%20mutation%20you%20made.%20Treat%20this.state%20as%20if%20it%20were%20immutable.). `const addTextArray = this.state.addText;` isn't creating a new array, `addTextArray`, but it's just a reference to `this.state.addText`

Comment: I would suggest you do `[...this.state.addText]` when assigning to the variable, that way there is no direct state manipulation.

Comment: My bad I missed it @DBS

Comment: Hi all, please see my comment on Mike's answer if you get the chance